# NameError: variable is not defined when searching for a keyword with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to scan multiple files and search for two keywords in the same line. I am trying to look for the keywords "SEQADV" and "MUTATION" in the same line. The problem is I keep getting the error "NameError: name 'wt_residue' is not defined".  When I search for one keyword "SEQADV", the program runs smoothly.

```
        if 'SEQADV' and 'MUTATION' in line:
            try:
                mutation = line.split()
                sequence_number = mutation[4]
                chain = mutation[3]
                mutant_residue = mutation[2]
                wt_residue = mutation[7]
            except IndexError:
                pass

#Prints all data to the .csv file above and closes the file 
            print(",".join([pdb_name, mutant_residue, chain, sequence_number, wt_residue]), file=datafile)    
datafile.close()
```

Comment: this line is incorrect `if 'SEQADV' and 'MUTATION' in line:` also `wt_residue` is undeclared if the code hits the except block

Comment: `except IndexError: pass` is a really bad idea. You're likely getting an error before that's assigned. Get rid of the `try`, and see if you get an error.

Comment: ok. I removed except IndexError: pass, but then I get another error saying "List Index Out of Range." How would I fix the if-statement please?

Comment: `if 'SEQADV' and 'MUTATION' in line:` is equivalent to `if 'MUTATION' in line:`. `'SEQADV'` is evaluated as a boolean expression and is always evaluated to `True` in that context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your if statement to `if 'SEQADV' in line.split() and 'MUTATION' in line.split():`

Comment: thank you, i don't know why I didn't think of this but it worked

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.